# Is it necessary to buy a wireless adaptor from the same brand as the router?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Is it necessary to buy a D-Link wireless adaptor for D-link router for good performance or can I buy any adaptor of any brand?

---

I have a D-link [DIR-655 Wi-fi Router](http://www.dlink.com/DIR-655) and I need to buy a Wi-fi adaptor for my Desktop. D-link's website has a tab for this router named "Work with", which suggests some router for the desktop.

[image]

But for suggested adapter I found [very negative reviews](http://reviews.cnet.com/adapters-nics/d-link-xtreme-n/4505-3380_7-32340968.html).

**So Is it necessary to buy a wireless adaptor from the same brand as the router for good performance or can I buy any adaptor of any brand which has positive reviews?**

Comment: … this is just marketing. Of course they want you to buy their stuff, but the "working with" does not exclude other WiFi adaptors. That's why these things are standardized. You should be good to go with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all.  Except for the odd case here and there, it should not matter whatsoever what brand it is, as long as they are compatible from a Wireless B/G/N point of view.

I myself have numerous brands throughout my network and have had no compatibility issues to this point.  And I know many others for whom it is the same case.

Comment: In the early days of each standard, you typically wouldn't want to do this, but A/B/G/N are all pretty established now and problems between brands are much rarer (though not impossible).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any adapter/router combination you like, as long as they use the same standard (A/B/G/N). Sometimes they'll work a bit better together if you use the same brand, but this is more in third-party features, like connecting the adapter to the router, or some software tool you probably don't need.

Also, some of the superboost (among dozens of other names) Wireless-G adapters could be brand-specific; another brand might only connect at "normal" Wireless-G speeds. But since N is superior to superboost G, and no real price difference for the devices, I would just go with that.